# Spark is throwing FileNotFoundException while accessing cached table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

There is a table which I read early in the script, but it will fail during run if the underlying table changes in a partition I read in e.g.:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
hdfs://R2/projects/.../country=AB/date=2021-08-20/part-00005e4-4fa5-aab4-93f02feaf746.c000
```

Even when I specifically cache the table, and do an action, the script will still fail down the line if the above happens.

```
df.cache()
df.show(1)
```

My question is, how is this possible?
If I cache the data on memory/disk, why does it matter if the underlying file is updated or not?

Edit: the code is very long, the main thing:

1. df= read in table, whose underlying data is in the above HDFS folder
2. df. cache() and df.show() immediately after it, since Spark evaluates lazily. With show() I make the caching happening
3. Later when I refer to df: if underlying data is changed, script will fail with java.io.FileNotFoundException:

   ```
    new_df= df.join(
    other_df, 'id', 'right')
   ```

Comment: Could you provide more information about the code you're running ? Spark are made of lazy transformations which are not computed right away, which could mislead you on what's actually happening with the data. More info about that [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

Comment: that is why I do an action right after caching, to make sure the caching is executed.

Comment: What is the line that throws an exception?

Comment: added, just a right join

Comment: Spark will automatically evict the cached data whenever it's out of  memory. Put one sleep statement above the join condition and check on spark UI- storage tab and verify if cached data is still available.

Comment: ah this most likely solves it. Since it can evict, there is no guarantee it will be there. I have to give more memory I suppose, thanks

Comment: @MohanaBC wondering, could this be avoided by caching on DISK-only?

Comment: I never checked that. could you please check that using df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY) and update here.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comment section, Spark will automatically evict the cached data based on LRU(Lease Recently Utilized) concept whenever it encounters out of memory issue.

In your case spark might have evicted the cached table. If there is no cached data then previous lineage will be used to form the dataframe again and it will throw an error if the underlying file is missing.

You can try increasing the memory or use storage level as DISK_ONLY.

```
 df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```